# how to stop MPMedia player when current UIView change

Tags: xcode, uiview

How to stop MPMedia Player when UIView is not the current visbile ? I am making scroll pages application. When the use scroll to next page, the MPMedia player still playing in the background. How to stop. Is any function can notice  UIView is not currently on top front visbile?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a bug in the framework.

Answer (score 0):

To determine whether a `UIView` is visible or not, you can check if:

- it is hidden, by checking `view.hidden`
- it is in the view hierarchy, by checking `view.superview == nil`
- the bounds of the view are on screen

There is no easy method that determines whether or not a `UIView` is visible.

Comment: Hi:Is any one know how to use viewWithTag? I think it maybe is my best option right now. I need to find out  away to track which UIview is on the front.